# Super Training, EV's, and Exp. Share

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Okay, so I've looked online and I haven't really found anything that answers this question, which I found kind of surprising...

Essentially, I have a full team of 6 pokemon, all fully trained through Super Training (i.e. they can't get anymore EV's or 'Base Stats' from Super Training). Does this mean that they no longer acquire EV's from battle and I don't have to worry about my pokemon getting unwanted EV's, or will using the Exp. Share still botch their growth?

TL;DR: I have 6 pokemon fully Super Trained, so can I safely use the Exp. Share without worrying about them getting the wrong EV's in battle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are fully EV trained (i.e, each pokemon has 512EVs), then it can no longer gain any more Effort Values, so you are safe to kill anything.